# Unable to create a constant value of type 'Gpc.Domain.Model.FeatureValues'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

This is making me so frustrated, i have done this 1000 times but i can't get this to work now for some reason. 
I have created a view connecting two tables and it looks like this:

[image]

then i have my request object looking like this:
[image]

Then i'm trying to do a pretty simple query using .Any like this:

```
      var result = gpcContext.GetFeatureOptionEcom.Where(a => a.LanguageCode == languageCode && features.Any(b => b.FeatureValue == a.Feature));
        return result;
```

and i get the error [image]

I have done a lot of lambdas with any before and i have got this message before but then it always was that i needed to grab the values from the database with tolist or something before using the values again so that they weren't lazyloaded. Can this have something to do with the view i'm using?

If i instead of using .Any just write a specific featureValue it works fine, so then it can't be the view that is not correct?

Comment: try using string.Equals(b.FeatureValue, a.Feature) to compare b.FeatureValue with  a.Feature, i think that EF can't translate the query because it's trying to compare references instead of values

Comment: If this was what you meant?  var result = gpcContext.GetFeatureOptionEcom.Where(a => a.LanguageCode == languageCode && features.Any(b => string.Equals(a.Feature, b.FeatureValue)));
            return result;

Then i still get the same error :(

Comment: if that doesn't work, could you try a.Feature.Equals(b.FeatureValue)

Comment: Still same result :(

Comment: i think the problem is with featureValues object, could you rewrite the any statement as this features.Select(t=>t.FeatureValue).Contains(a.Feature), if it doesn't work could you save the list of strings in a variable before and then use it in the query, var featuresString = features.Select(t=>t.FeatureValue), the use featuresString.Contains(a.Feature)